# Getting an exact real solution of a transcendental equation

Tags: equation-solving

I want to get the solution of

```
E^(2x) - E^x == 6
```

I tried

```
FindRoot[E^(2x) - E^x == 6, {x, 1}]
```

which gave me the numerical aproximation

> ```
> {x -> 1.09861}
> ```

But I need the exact value `Log[3]`. I tried `Solve`, but it returns a complicated result that I don't want.

How can I get `Log[3]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FindRoot` looks for numeric solutions.  You might want to try

```
Solve[E^(2 x) - E^x == 6, x, Reals]
```

and see how that goes for you.  Note that I've written `E` to represent Euler's number.

Comment: This really works, very usefull your awser.